# Copying a generic list to another, with different data types takes too long (C#)

Tags: c#, devexpress, aspxgridview, generic-list

I have a `List<CallLog>`, where `CallLog` has the following properties:

```
public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
public string SomePropertyN { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public DateTime CallEndTime { get; set; }
```

I need to fill a (devexpress) grid data source with this list. The grid has the following columns:

Date | SomeProperty1 | SomeProperty2 | ... | SomePropertyN | CallStartTime | CallEndTime

In fact, I am using the `Date` property in 2 columns, in the first column (Date), I use only the `date` part and in the other column (CallStartTime), I use the `time` part only.

Unfortunately, `gridxview` fails to perform proper grouping when I simply ask it to show different formats of my `Date` property in 2 columns. So, I decided to create a customized class and copy the original list into a new list (`List<CustomizedCallLog>`) and pass the new list as the grid data source. Below is how I am doing this. But it takes too long. Is there any fast way to copy the list?

My customized call log class:

```
Public Class CustomizedCalLog
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string SomePropertyN { get; set; }
    public string CallStartTime { get; set; }
    public string CallEndTime { get; set; }

    public CustomizedCallLog(CallLog log)
    {
        this.Date = log.Date;
        this.SomeProperty1 = log.SomeProperty1 ;
        this.SomeProperty2 = log.SomeProperty2 ;
        this.SomePropertyN = log.SomePropertyN ;
        this.CallStartTime = log.Date.ToString("H:mm");
        this.CallEndTime = log.CallEndTime.ToString("H:mm");           
    }        
}
```

Setting the grid:

```
private void SetGrid()
{
    var logs = someBusiness.GetLogs();
    List<CustomizedCallLog> dataSource = new List<CustomizedCallLog>();
    foreach (var log in logs)
    {
        dataSource.Add(new CustomizedCallLog(log));
    }

    grid.ForceDataRowType(typeof(CustomizedCallLog));
    grid.DataSource = dataSource;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: *Below is how I am doing this. But it takes too long.* Have you benchmarked your code? Are you certain the bottleneck lays with the copying of the list?

Comment: You're right, the bottleneck is with `this.SomePropertyX = log.SomePropertyX ;` Thanks!

Comment: I think you can try this way, dont create a new class, but add these two new properties to the existing class it self. and in the getters of the two properties you just return the the formatted string. some thing like this ..

Comment: class CallLog 
    {
        public string SomeProperty1 { get; set; }
        public string SomeProperty2 { get; set; }
        public string SomePropertyN { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime CallEndTime { get; set; }
        public string CallStartTime { get { return Date.ToString("H:mm"); } set; }
        public string CallEndTime2 { get { return CallEndTime.ToString("H:mm"); } set; }
    }
If you like this please let me know i will add this as answer.

Comment: Is this solved or you still face the issue

Comment: @kishoreVM Yes, thank you for your comments. I added an answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is resolved using the comment by  @Yuval Itzchakov.

I could not add the new properties to my existing class since the existing class was auto-generated (with some .tt file).

So, I left the code as it is, and improved the `this.SomePropertyX = log.SomePropertyX` bit of code which was making a bottleneck.